# writing about cultural differences

Tags: word-usage, culture

Did I use the word **"Task"** appropriately in the following sentence:

> Living in a foreign country could be a challenging **task** for everyone.

How can I say in a formal writing that the difference between the origin culture and the destination culture is huge?

Is "**In case of huge cultural differences**" used appropriately in the following sentence:

> It is more challenging to get adopted **in case of huge cultural difference.**

Comment: Do you have a *specific cause of concern*? Otherwise it looks awfully like general proofreading, which is off-topic here.

Comment: "Living in a foreign country could be a challenging task for everyone." - just as an idiomatic usage note, I think it would be better to say **anyone**, not **everyone**.  Afterall, *everyone* is not going to be living in a foreign country, but *any* of us might be.

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatically I don't think *in case of X* works very well in OP's specific context. It's usually used in contexts like...

> 1: [*He felt like an invalid because he now wore nappies **in case of** accidents.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wore%20nappies%20in%20case%20of%22)

...where *in case of* effectively means *as a precautionary / ameliorative* measure (either to prevent accidents happening at all, or to limit the bad effects if they do).

It also appears in the standard instructions on fire alarm button behind protective glass...

> 2: [***In case of*** fire break glass](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in%20case%20of%20fire%20break%20glass%22)

...where *in case of* means ***if*** [there is a] fire. Thus in #1 the specified action (wearing nappies) happens *whether or not* there's an accident, but in #2 you only break the glass *if* there's a fire.

To my mind, the connection between these two distinct usages turns on the fact that the specified action is a *purposeful response* to a [possible] situation (involuntary excretion, fire, whatever). That's my first reason for saying it doesn't work very well in OP's context (there's no purposeful response).

---

My second reason for not liking it can be illustrated by considering...

> 3: *The doctor prescribed antibiotics **in case of** infection*

...which native speakers will *always* interpret as meaning the antibiotics are ***always*** prescribed (to *prevent* infection), rather ***only if*** the situation (a case of infection) arises (to *cure* it). To specifically convey that second meaning requires ***cases*** to be cast in the plural...

> 4: *The doctor prescribed antibiotics **in cases of** infection*

Thus in principle OP's meaning can be conveyed by...

> 5: *It is more challenging to get adopted **in cases of** huge cultural difference*

...but in practice this is somewhat clumsy phrasing. Plus the connotations of "cases" being "undesirable, but fixable" situations don't really apply here. So I'd prefer...

> 6: *It is more challenging to get adopted **if / where there is a** huge cultural difference*